# How to remove a row in HTML if the attribute is empty in the AD(Active Directory)?

Tags: javascript, html, email, outlook, signature

I have set up an email signature using HTML, and it is gathering information from the active directory via Office365.
I have gathered all the data I need, but I want a row to be deleted if no data of an attribute is present.
In the example below I want to delete the row with 'm: %%MobileNumber%%' if the mobile number isn't present in the directory.
This is all being controlled by HTML and through the mail rules in the admin center of Office365.

I have used jQuery and Javascript but there seems to be multiple issues, but this is the closest I have gotten. The number shows in mobile when available, but the 'm: ' in mobile is still visible.

```js
function() {

  $('td').each(function() {
    var str = $(this).text();
    var sub = str.substring(
      str.indexOf('m: ', 1) + 1
    );
    if (sub == ' ') {
      // or .remove()
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Email Signature</title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table style="width: 400px; font-size:9pt; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; line-height:16px;;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size:12pt; line-height:19px; padding:1px; padding-bottom:8px;  width:259px;">
          <span style="font-size:12pt; font-weight: bold">%%FirstName%% %%LastName%%</span>
          <span style="font-size:10pt;"><br/> %%Title%% </span>
        </td>
      </tr><br/>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:400px; font-size:10pt; color: #2c2c2c; padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px;" colspan="2" width="400">t: %%HomePhoneNumber%%
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td id="number" style="width:400px; font-size:10pt; color: #2c2c2c; padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px;">m: %%MobileNumber%%</td>
        </tr>
        <td style="width:400px; font-size:10pt; color: #2c2c2c; padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px;" colspan="2" width="400">e: %%email%% </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect when the attribute %%MobileNumber%% reads no mobile number within the directory, the row would delete.